# Adding a trailing comma after the last item of tuple

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I am using sqlite3 which requires us to put trailing comma after the last item of tuple (of values). The example below should return an expected output of `(2, 3,)`. Is there a builtin function that can handle this?

```
args = 2, 3

print(args)
# (2, 3)

print((args,))
# ((2, 3),)
```

sqlite3 without trailing comma after 'John'

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE first_name = ?", ('John'))
print(c.fetchall())
conn.close()

# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The
# current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

sqlite3 with trailing comma after 'John'

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE first_name = ?", ('John',))
print(c.fetchall())
conn.close()

# [(1, 'John')]
```

Comment: Where does sqlite3 require that?

Comment: I've got `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied`. The way I solve the problem is to add a trailing comma on the last part of the tuple.

Comment: I think the op uses sqllite3 package in python.

Comment: If you have a problem with your code, you need to show your code.

Comment: I don't think the trailing comma is required, but it might be good coding practice.

Comment: Trailing commas are only required for tuples of 1 element

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't know why sqlite3 required to include trailing comma.

Comment: Can you share the line of code that is causing the error?

Comment: @joumaico, sqlite **doesn't** require the trailing comma. `(2,3)` and `(2,3,)` are completely identical; no code, sqlite included, can tell them apart.

Comment: @joumaico, ...by contrast, `t1=(2,3); t2=(t1,)` is different from `t1=(2,3); t2=(t1)`, because the latter assigns `t1` directly to `t2`, instead of enclosing it in a tuple.

Comment: @joumaico, ...it's basically certain that you've got a situation like that -- where you're generating a nested tuple in one case, and a literal tuple in the other case; but the question isn't giving us enough details to address the root cause with complete certainty.

Comment: @IainShelvington I've already updated the post.

Comment: In `c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE first_name = ?", ('John'))`, `('John')` **is not a tuple at all**; it only becomes a tuple when you add the comma. As soon as something is a tuple, though, whether or not there's a trailing comma is moot.

Comment: No there not a built-in as behavior is correct. By `args = 2, 3` you create a tuple, which you can prove by typing `type(args)`. By putting `args` within brackets and adding a comma `(args,)` you create a tuple of tuples. Without the comma args would just stay a tuple, like you can put  `1+1` within brackects `(1+1)` and get the same result of 2.

Comment: BTW, the "four arguments" the error message talks about are the four letters in the string `John`; as when a string is treated as a sequence, one gets the individual characters.

Comment: The point is that `sqlite3` requires a `tuple` parameter when using `?` placeholders, even if only one.  The trailing comma is just part of python's syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statements differ in the following detail:

```
('John')  ## this is not a tuple, it just evaluates to the string 'John'
('John',) ## this *is* a tuple, containing a string 'John' as its only element
```

---

However, that difference exists **only** in the case where a tuple has only one item.

```
('John', 'Sue') == ('John', 'Sue',)
```

...is a true statement, because as soon as you have more than one item, the value unambiguously parses as a tuple; no trailing comma is needed.

Comment: Thank you, accidentally I `args = 1,` to make the args a tuple instead of string.

Comment: I have finally seen the exact term for this: `In Python, a tuple containing a single value must include a comma. For example, ('abc') is evaluated as a scalar while ('abc',) is evaluated as a tuple.` Thank you Charles. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Because you are using a tuple and a comma is required if you have one element. Use a list instead by replacing your parenthesis () with brackets [].