# Correct syntax for python-sqlite3 script? How to select all rows that has a column with a specific value?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I wrote the following python-sqlite3 code. It has two issues:

1. I want to understand how to write a SQLite3 statement to extract all rows with "cola". What is the correct syntax for the `.get_fav_drink_folks(drink) method`?

   Error:

   ```
   line 25, in get_fav_drink_folks self.cur.execute(sql, drink)
   sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
   ```

Script:

```
import sqlite3

class DB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.create_table()

    def create_table(self):
        table = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
            database (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
                      fav_food TEXT,
                      fav_drink TEXT
                      )"""
        self.cur.execute(table)
        self.con.commit()

    def insert_data_row(self, items):
        sql = """INSERT OR IGNORE INTO database VALUES(?,?,?)"""
        self.cur.execute(sql, items)
        self.con.commit()

    def get_fav_drink_folks(self, drink):
        sql = """SELECT * FROM database WHERE fav_drink in (?)"""
        self.cur.execute(sql, drink)
        return self.cur.fetchmany()


if __name__ in "__main__":
    db = DB()
    data = [
        ("Mike", "Steak", "Cola",),
        ("Dora", "McDonalds", "Sprite",),
        ("Sally", "Salad", "Pepsi",),
        ("Eve", "Pizza", "Cola",),
        ]
    for row_items in data:
        print(f"{row_items=}")
        db.insert_data_row(row_items)
    print(f"\ncoke_drinkers are {db.get_fav_drink_folks('Cola')}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're not instantiating the class.
   `db = DB` should be `db = DB()`
2. you pass `get_fav_drink_folks` a string and then use it on `self.cur.execute(sql, items)`

You need a tuple like in the other function.

Either you `self.cur.execute(sql, (drink,))` or you `cola_drinkers = db.get_fav_drink_folks(('Cola',))`

Edit:

As for the tuple comma, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734760/5640517

Comment: Silly me.... `db = DB()` fixed q1. How about q2? This is the main issue. I will update my question.

Comment: @SunBear also keep in mind for future questions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions TL;DR is if your original question has been answered accept the answer and open a new question for the newfound error

Comment: One more improvement to your answer. `fetchall` should replace `fetchmany` in  the `.get_fav_drink_folks(drink)` method. If not, only a row of data is returned.